# Java lambda-expressions with miscellaneous operands

Tags: java, lambda, interface, java-8, operator-overloading

This lambda expressions work perfectly for math-operations with two operands (a and b).

```
public class Math {
  interface IntegerMath {
    int operation(int a, int b);       
  }

  private static int apply(int a, int b, IntegerMath op) {
    return op.operation(a, b);
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    IntegerMath addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
    IntegerMath subtraction = (a, b) -> a - b;
    System.out.println("40 + 2 = " + apply(40, 2, addition));
    System.out.println("20 - 10 = " + apply(20, 10, subtraction));

  }
}
```

How can you enhance this class with possible *unary* operations for example

```
IntergerMath square = (a) -> a * a;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with `IntegerMath`, since it's a functional interface whose single abstract method takes two `int` arguments. You'll need a new interface for unary operations.

BTW, you don't have to define those interfaces yourself. `java.util.function` contains interfaces you can use, such as `IntUnaryOperator` and `IntBinaryOperator`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it because the `square` method does not have the same signature.

Note that you could also use an `IntBinaryOperator` and an `IntUnaryOperator` (which as you can notice are completely separate) instead of creating your own interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

> You'll need a new interface for unary operations.

```
public class Math {
  interface BinMath {
    int operation(int a, int b);

  }

  interface UnMath {
    int operation(int a);

  }

  private static int apply(int a, int b, BinMath op) {
    return op.operation(a, b);
  }

  private static int apply(int a, UnMath op) {
    return op.operation(a);
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    BinMath addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
    BinMath subtraction = (a, b) -> a - b;
    UnMath square = (a) -> a * a;

    System.out.println("40 + 2 = " + apply(40, 2, addition));
    System.out.println("20 - 10 = " + apply(20, 10, subtraction));
    System.out.println("20² = " + apply(20, square));

  }
}
```